# Passing a self parameter to a member function

Tags: python

I was told by someone to never pass a self dot paramter (`self.paramter`) to a member method. Here's what I mean:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, parameter_one, parameter_two):
        self._parameter_one = parameter_one
        self._parameter_two = parameter_two
        self._result = None
        self.do_something(param1 = self._parameter_one, param2 = self._parameter_two)
    def do_something(self, param1, param2):
        self._result = param1 * param2
        print(self._result)
```

I make the call and it works:

`>>> a = my_class(2, 5)
10`

Why is this bad to do? It isn't against any PEP8 that I know of. If I set the self.parameters by the ones passed in the constructor (maybe I've done some processing of them before storing in self) I wouldn't want to process again before passing to the class method.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is because a class method already has access to the object you're using to call the method.  You're giving the method two different paths to access the same data, and that alias is not obvious within the called method's code.  Instead, you should do something like this:
        ...
        self.do_something()

```
def do_something(self):
    self._result = self._parameter_one * self._parameter_two
    print(self._result)
```

Do you see the difference?  This way, it's specifically clear that you're using attributes (fields) of the symbiont object to perform the calculation.  The way you posted doesn't show that.  In more complex designs, it's easy to miss that `param1` is derived directly from the *given* object -- and make a fatal error that's hard to trace.

Comment: This is only true if `do_something` is only supposed to operate on properties of itself. If you can also call it with unrelated data, then it's just a special case when the parameters are from `self`.

Comment: Calling it with unrelated data likely should be a separate class method.  For instance, `do_something_inside` vs `do_something_external`.

Comment: That seems redundant. What if you can call it internally with different properties? Should it be a different method for each combination?

Comment: I think the biggest risk is there is a danger of modifying the object accidentally through one of the parameters, if it enters the function via several routes. Especially when said parameters aren't always expected to be assigned from the object parameters.

Comment: That depends on the overall system design.  For two cases, internal and external data, I'd use separate methods to avoid the aliasing problem (semantic, not syntactic, in this case).  I'm hardly a structure purist; generalize the problem somehow, and I'll flip back, documenting the self.<attribute> calls.